# Decorator on methods checking for instance variable

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I have a python class, `Something`. I would like to create a method, `borrowed`, which would check for whether the instance variable `blue` of `Something` is `None`.

How would I create `@check_none` on the instance method so that it would check for an instance variable? Using `self` in the decorator function did not work ;(

Example:

```
def check_token(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        if self.token == None:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

class Something(object):
   def __init__(self, token=None):
      self.token = token

   @check_token
   def testfunction(self):
      print "Test"
```

Yields a `global name 'self' is not defined` error.

Comment: Edited with attempt. Thank you.

Comment: See, you forgot to add `self` to the `inner()` function signature. Don't forget to pass it on the the `func()` call. Alternatively, use `self = args[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inner function doesn't have a `self` argument; add it in and pass it on:

```
def check_token(func):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.token is None:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

The `inner` function replaces the original method when decorated and is passed in the same `self` argument.

Alternatively, you can use `args[0].token`, since `self` is simply the first positional argument.

Note that I replaced your `== None` test with the recommended `is None` test.

Demo:

```
>>> def check_token(func):
...     def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         if self.token is None:
...             raise ValueError
...         else:
...             return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
...     return inner
... 
>>> class Something(object):
...    def __init__(self, token=None):
...       self.token = token
...    @check_token
...    def testfunction(self):
...       print "Test"
... 
>>> Something().testfunction()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in inner
ValueError
>>> Something('token').testfunction()
Test
```